# About character constant and Unicode in C

Tags: c

I got a warning about this:

```
warning: character constant too long for its type
     printf("%x %x\n",'\U12345678',U'\U12345678');
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

> The Output is:8d8599b8  12345678

I want to know the reason.Why too long and the first value is strange?
I think '\U12345678' use 4 bytes and has int type(4 byte).
Such as 'abcd'(output:61626364) is ok,not warn too long,only warn multi-character.

```
info:
     windows 10
     x86_64-w64-mingw32
     gcc version 8.1.0
```

Can someone explain this phenomenon? Thanks very much.

Comment: Even though character constants are `int` (or `unsigned int`), multi-byte character constants are implementation defined.

Comment: Besides, `'abcd'` is a multi-character constant, but `'\U12345678'` is a single multi-byte character. These are two different beasts.

Comment: Why would you use such code anyway?

Comment: Without `U` prefix in first case probably the character is interpreted as ANSI (8-bit).

Comment: @PetrTesařík "Beasts",i like this word. :)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I am just curious about it, and don't intend to use it for practical purposes.  :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of a multi-character character constant, or a single-character character constant whose representation in the execution character set is more than one byte long, is implementation defined.

GCC defines it to be the number formed by interpreting the byte sequence in memory as a big-endian binary number. If overflow occurs, the high bytes are lost, and a warning is issued.

Now, your execution character set is most likely UTF-8 (default that can be changed with the `-fexec-charset` command-line option), so \U12345678 (which, as a matter of fact, is outside the UCS codespace) is encoded as a sequence of 6 bytes:

```
$ echo -ne '\x12\x34\x56\x78' | iconv --from=ucs-4be --to=utf8 | od -tx1
0000000 fc 92 8d 85 99 b8
0000006
```

The `int` type on your target appears to be 4 bytes long, so the first two bytes are lost, and the remaining bytes are interpreted as big endian 0x8d8599b8, and that's the actual number printed out.